# How to get the mime-type of a get response in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building an app that uploads any image(.jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif) to aws s3 bucket. And then fetching the response as an arraybuffer.
As shown here.

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    this.fetchUserProfileImage(this.state.id).then((response) => {
        const data = response.data;
        const base64String = btoa(String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(data)));
        this.setState({
            imageUrl: base64String,
        });
    });
};
fetchUserProfileImage = async (userProfileId) => {
    return await axios.get(
        `http://localhost:5000/api/v1/users/${userProfileId}/image/download`,
        {
            responseType: 'arraybuffer',
        }
    );
};
```

Since the response is an array buffer and not an actual file with a mime-type like myimage.png or a image link.
How do i come to know mime type for different images from this.

```
<img src={`data:image/jpeg;base64,${this.state.imageUrl}`}
                        style={{ height: 50, width: 50 }}
                        alt='Rats'/>
```

I have tried using jpeg images only.
But if someone uploads a png or a gif, how would i handle that?

Getting the mime type would help to adjust the `data:image\${mime-type}`,so that i can change the `data:image/png;` or `data:image/jpg` accordingly.
Is there any fallback value if the image i have uploaded is a png or a gif and have the image src value is a jpeg.

```
`src={`data:image/jpeg;...}`
```

Update:
As suggested, I removed the `responseType:'arraybuffer'` from the request.
I uploaded 3 image .jpeg  .png and a .gif.
The response.headers is:

```
Object { "content-length": "4752", "content-type": "image/jpeg" }
App.js:97
Object { "content-length": "512604", "content-type": "image/jpeg" }
App.js:97
Object { "content-length": "1764904", "content-type": "image/jpeg" }
```

And the response.data is:

```
"����\u0000\u0010JFIF\u0000\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0000H\u0000H\u0000\u0000��\u0000C\u0000\u0004\u0003\u0003\u0003\u0003\u0002\u0004\u0003...."
```

Comment: Suggestion, when you upload itself capture the mime type to your DB via node js app. Then while rendering, read the mime type from the db via node app and retrieve file from AWS . Because these AWS URL you will persist in DB. Along with that persist the mime type. So the embed object / viewer you can decide accordingly and prevent from AWS file getting downloaded by default

Comment: Have you tried *not* putting the responseType, and see what response you get ? Maybe there are some headers there.